# How to defind selector tinyeditor as iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I have a html file:

```
<iframe id='myframe' src='#' name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" data-view="fullScreenPreview" >
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  document.getElementById('myframe').onload = function() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: $('#myframe').contents().find('body') ,
      inline: true,
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste'
      ],
      toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
    });
  };


  })

</script>
```

I want to defind tiny editor inline in iframe.
But when i use code above, it don't work.
How to init tinymce with body in iframe. 
Help me and tks.